# Python np.binom function only returns 1

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, binomial-coefficients

Probably a bit more of a maths question! I've got the following code that uses the binomial coefficent, np.binom to calculate propensity functions:

```
for j in range(len(LHS)):
cj = stoch_rate
for i in range(len(popul_num)): 
    if i >= LHS[i,j]:       # ensures discrete number of reactants is high enough for the reaction to occur according to the LHS ratios
        binon_rxn = binom(i, LHS[i, j])     # binomial coefficent isnt working! Always returns 1! 
        print(binon_rxn)        
        aj = cj*binon_rxn            
    else: 
        cj == 0           
        aj = (cj*binom(i, LHS[i, j]))
print("Propensity function:\n", aj)
```

The matrices I'm using are:

```
stoch_rate = np.matrix([0.0016, 0.0001, 0.1000])
LHS = np.matrix([[1,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0]])
popul_num = np.matrix([350, 700, 0, 0])
```

LHS represents the ratios between reactants in a system of 3 reactions (each row is a different reaction) and popul_num represents the discrete number of each reactant entity in the system. The reactants are; Enzyme, Substrate, Enzyme-Substrate complex and product which are represent in that order in each of the popul_num and LHS matrices. Stoch_rate is the rate of reaction.

I need to calculate the binomial coefficient using the number of discrete molecules in popul_num and the corresponding ratio for that reactant in that reaction from LHS.

At the moment my binomial coefficient always returns 1.0 and I dont know why?
I've tried scipy.stat.binom but that returns an attribute error "Scipy has no attribute stat' and scipy.special.binom but that also only returns 1.

Am I maybe not iterating over the matrix properly?

Cheers

Comment: `binom` is from `scipy.stats` not `numpy`

Comment: I've tried editing it to scipy.stats.binom but a get an attribute error no scipy has no attribute stats, I've tried using scipy.special.binom but still get only 1.0. do you think it could be an error with iterating over the matrix?

Comment: `len(popul_num)` is `1`, which is probably what catches you by surprise. This means that  `i` is always `0`. Don't use `np.matrix`, use `np.array` instead (unless you have a good reason).

Comment: I used a matrix because it makes indexing the cells of LHS easier, is it possible to keep LHS as a matrix but change popul_num into an array without getting the index error IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3?